# Copy data from a currently open browser window and paste into another program?

Tags: javascript, xml, groovy, soapui

I'm researching a method to accomplish what the title describes. Here's more detail:

I have an Internet Explorer window open with some fields filled with data. I have a programmed called SoapUI open that I need to fill with said data. I can, of course, copy and paste manually, but the nature of the tests I'm running will make this approach rather tedious. I'm looking for a way to automate it.

SoapUI has several active windows, the one which I am interested in is the XML request. There are various XML fields which I need to populate with the data that is open in a browser window on the same machine.

It is not as simple as writing a Groovy script to parse the HTML of a web address, because the data in the browser is filled dynamically with data from a piece of hardware. To the best of my knowledge, the URL does not change from the time the fields are empty to the time that the fields are filled with data.

If anyone has any ideas or can point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is using AutoHotKey an option?

You could get AHK to go to the URL, wait until the fields are filled and then do the copy/paste the way you would have done manually.